# regain regular expression search pattern while using less command

Tags: less

I need to regain regular expression search pattern while using less command. Is there any way to do that?. Once I start searching the expression disappears.

Comment: What do you mean by "regain the regular expression pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching in `less`, matches are highlighted, then you can use `n` (or `N`) to search for the next (resp. previous) pattern, and if typing `/` (to initiate a new search) but using the up/down arrow-keys you can get (inspect and modify) the previous entered regular expression.